# Wordpress city prefix to url as subdomain and subpage

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

How i can add this to wordpress, i create subdomain and folder for this subdomain is same with 
site.com
my homepage is have this code for getting the subdomain name

```
preg_match('/([^.]+)\.site\.com/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], $matches);
if(isset($matches[1])) {
    $subdomain = $matches[1];
}
if($subdomain=="cityname"){
    echo "Welcome to".$cityname ;
}else{ echo "Welcome to default city";}
```

i need to add rule for htaccess if any user enter to

```
$citynameprefix= array("new-york","LA","Boston","London");
foreach($citynameprefix as $cityprefix){
    $cityprefix.site.com/page
    site.com/cityprefix/page
}
```

cityname.site.com/page = site.com/cityname/page

cityname.site.com/cityname/ = 404 not found

Comment: What is the question/problem?

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson how i can add this to wordpress?

Comment: this is the way you SHOULD add rewrite rules in WP https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule Let me know if you need help with it.